# Signature: encoding a message - transaction to a point of curve y^2=x^3+7 and Bitcoin Core

Tags: signature, ecdsa, encoding

Where should I look at in [Bitcoin Core source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/secp256k1/src) to figure out how the signature process trasform a message in a curve point?

To sign a transaction (message) in Bitcoin system, you need to encode the message to a point of the curve y^2=x^3+7. I read this [Koblitz's paper](http://math.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/MATH508/KoblitzEmbedding.pdf). There are three encoding schemes. I read [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24240/koblitz-encoding-a-message-to-a-point-what-is-the-associated-auxiliary-base-pa) too.

If I look at in Bitcoin Core source code I can't see any of these encoding schemes, it seems to me that message M is directly encoded in a point m=hash(M) without check; obviously that is not possible, there is roughly a 50% chance that a random 256 bit string don't correspond to a point of the curve. I can't find out how/if the ECDSA library checks if hash(M) is on the curve or not and especially what it does if the hash(M) is not on the curve.

What encoding scheme does Bitcoin-ECDSA implement and where is it in the source code?

Thanks and sorry for my English.

EDIT:

Bitcoin: Signature generation (ECDSA)

Given a message m to be signed and the private key d,

1. Choose a random integer k in [1,n-1].
2. Compute (x1,y1)=kP, convert x1 into integer and r = x1 mod n.(Return to step1 if r = 0)
3. Computes=(k^-1)*(**SHA1(m)**+ dr). (Return to step 1 if s= 0)
4. Signature is (r, s) pair.

**Why SHA1(m) should be a curve point?** There is only a 50% chance.

Comment: I assume you're talking about section 3. These look like ways of encrypting something using ECDSA, not ways of signing a message.

Comment: arulbero, are you having trouble pasting something in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To sign a transaction (message) in Bitcoin system, you need to encode the message to a point of the curve y^2=x^3+7

Perhaps you're thinking of [ElGamal *encryption*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption), whereby you *do* need to select a point on the curve which represents your plaintext.

However for *signing*, Bitcoin uses [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm), and this has no such requirement.

If you're interested, the code which implements ECDSA signing is in secp256k1_ecdsa_sig_sign(). For example, [this is the code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/fec5c0ea05ec22e12313ce3ec575786f5c52039f/src/secp256k1/src/ecdsa_impl.h#L244-L247) which implements step 6 from the Wikipedia link above.

Comment: Why "Bitcoin uses ECDSA and this has no such requirement" ?  In the Wikipedia link, at step 6 you use "z = HASH(m)", and then z  must be a curve point.

Comment: @arulbero Why does z need to be a curve point? It's added to rd<sub>a</sub>, which is a scalar.

Comment: You're right!  I thought that "r" was a curve point, but it isn't!  Thank you very much!